# Why my implementation of IDocHostUIHandler is ignored

Tags: c#, .net, browser, webbrowser-control

I have created derived control from `WebBrowser` control that has own `IDocHostUIHandler` implementation following idea from [`CreateWebBrowserSiteBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.createwebbrowsersitebase%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method:

> The WebBrowser.WebBrowserSite class provides default implementations
>   of the OLE IDocHostUIHandler interface. You can provide your own
>   implementation of this interface or implement any other WebBrowser
>   ActiveX control interface in order to customize the behavior of the
>   control.

The problem that is not working. My code looks next way:

```
[PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Name = "FullTrust")]
public MyBrowser(){}

protected override WebBrowserSiteBase CreateWebBrowserSiteBase()
{
    var manager = new NewWebBrowserSite(this);
    return manager;
}

protected class NewWebBrowserSite : WebBrowserSite, 
    UnsafeNativeMethods.IDocHostUIHandler
{
    private MyBrowser host;
    public NewWebBrowserSite(MyBrowser h)
        : base(h)
    {
        this.host = h; 
    }

    int UnsafeNativeMethods.IDocHostUIHandler.ShowContextMenu(int dwID, NativeMethods.POINT pt, object pcmdtReserved, object pdispReserved)
    {
        MyBrowser wb = (MyBrowser)this.host;
        // other code
    }

    // rest of IDocHostUIHandler methods
}
```

My questions are:

1. Do I have to implement other interfaces to make it working;
2. Is that by design, I have read some [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/79c1f5a7-372e-4777-84e5-862d3f14267f/) that it is related to a bug in .net framework implementation of `WebBrowser`

I know that is possible to go [`ICustomDoc.SetUIHandler`](http://www.codeproject.com/csharp/advhost.asp) way, but it is not what I am looking for.

I was having idea at some point to give up with c# and do that with unmanaged code. Is that the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply override the interfaces implemented by a class. If the methods for IDocHostUIHandler are not marked as virtual, you can't replace them.

The fact that the interface is defined in `UnsafeNativeMethods` is also a clue that you probably shouldn't be messing with it unless you have a very good idea of what you're doing.

Answer (score 4):

I've just dealt with exactly the same problem: how to provide a custom implementation of `IDocHostUIHandler` to WinForms `WebBrowser` control. The problem is that the base class `WebBrowserSite` has already implemented its own version of `IDocHostUIHandler` (which is an `internal` interface, so it's not possible to [explicitly re-implement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664593%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) it in the derived class `NewWebBrowserSite`). However, in theory it should not be a problem to implement another C# interface with the same GIID and methods layout (because that's all the COM client - the underlying WebBrowser ActiveX Control - cares about in this particular case).

Unfortunately, it was not possible until .NET 4.0. Luckily, now it is, by means of the new [ICustomQueryInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.icustomqueryinterface.aspx) feature:

```
protected class NewWebBrowserSite : WebBrowserSite, 
    UnsafeNativeMethods.IDocHostUIHandler
    ICustomQueryInterface
{
    private MyBrowser host;
    public NewWebBrowserSite(MyBrowser h): base(h)
    {
        this.host = h; 
    }

    int UnsafeNativeMethods.IDocHostUIHandler.ShowContextMenu(int dwID, NativeMethods.POINT pt, object pcmdtReserved, object pdispReserved)
    {
        MyBrowser wb = (MyBrowser)this.host;
        // other code
    }

    // rest of IDocHostUIHandler methods

    // ICustomQueryInterface

    public CustomQueryInterfaceResult GetInterface(ref Guid iid, out IntPtr ppv)
    {
        if (iid == typeof(UnsafeNativeMethods.IDocHostUIHandler).GUID)
        {
            ppv = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(this, typeof(UnsafeNativeMethods.IDocHostUIHandler), CustomQueryInterfaceMode.Ignore);
        }
        else
        {
            ppv = IntPtr.Zero;
            return CustomQueryInterfaceResult.NotHandled;
        }
        return CustomQueryInterfaceResult.Handled;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to call `Marshal.Release`

Comment: @PaulB., to call it where exactly?

Comment: Oh, I think you are right, the caller of `QueryInterface` is responsible for that, sorry.